# iOS Overlay view which always sits on top?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I haven't been able to find anything on this and feel it likely isn't possible in a simple manner.

Can I have a view, such a loading bar for example which constantly sits over every other view controller until I choose to dismiss it but at the same time any underlying view can still be interacted with? Sort of acting like a system view. Be persistent when presenting new view controllers and all.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already seen such an app or system view?

Answer (score 4):

Add it as a subview of your `window`. Like this:

```
UIView *myView = ...
[self.window addSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than adding it to the window, as @JackyBoy suggests, add it to the window's rootViewController's view. That will rotate along with the device. If you just add it to the window, you may have problems with rotation.

```
UIView *myView = ...
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:myView];
```